# How to get Pagination plugin class names dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, jquery-pagination

I am trying to get the class names dynamically for the script below.

I am using the Pagination plugin. I have different class names that are created through PHP so need to get them using jQuery dynamically.

As you can see below, there are two '#hiddenresult div.result'. 'result' is the static class name that needs to change since the class name will be populated with PHP

The jQuery file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq){
        var new_content = $('#hiddenresult div.result:eq('+page_index+')').clone();
        $('#Searchresult').empty().append(new_content);
        return false;
    }

    /** 
     * Callback function for the AJAX content loader.
     */
    function initPagination() {
        var num_entries = $('#hiddenresult div.result').length;
        // Create pagination element
        $("#Pagination").pagination(num_entries, {
            num_edge_entries: 2,
            num_display_entries: 8,
            callback: pageselectCallback,
            items_per_page:1
        });
     }

    // Load HTML snippet with AJAX and insert it into the Hiddenresult element
    // When the HTML has loaded, call initPagination to paginate the elements        
    $(document).ready(function(){      
        initPagination();
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the problem but if you are trying to get the class names,

you can always:

```
$('selector').attr('class'); // returns all the class names
```

also you may

```
$('selector').removeClass('classname'); // remove a class named classname
$('selector').addClass('classname'); // adds a class named classname
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm having difficulty implementing it in the script above. Anyone know of the proper implantation?